# Are all values of $\sin(x)$ algebraic.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can we prove that for all $x$ in $(0,2\pi)$ $\sin(x)$ is an algebraic number?

I have seen people express various values of $\sin(x)$ like $\sin(3)$ and $\sin(30)$ using radicals so I suspect that all values of $\sin(x)$ must be algebraic. Is that correct? Can we prove it?

Comment: No. The set of algebraic numbers is countable, but sin(x) spans [-1,1], which is uncountable.

Comment: I'd actually be interested in the question of *which* values of $\sin$ are algebraic. I know all values of the form $\sin(2\pi r)$ where $r$ is a rational number are.

Comment: All values $\sin(x)$ are algebraic, where $x$ is an integer number of degrees.  Maybe that's what Adam asks.  Of course Timotej's answer is more general than this.

Comment: Yep, I was mostly thinking about integer degrees, when I asked the question, but the answers pretty much hit the spot for me anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quick answer: no.  Consider that $\sin$ is continuous over the range $[-1,1]$, and thus can take on values such as $e^{-1}, \frac 2\pi$, etc.

Comment: From here, we could also argue that any nonconstant polynomial has nonalgebraic values. I could also dare to say that any function that is continuous somewhere takes nonalgebraic values.

Comment: @chubakueno: that is correct, and the answer is that they will.  The missing piece is that all non-constant polynomials having algebraic coefficients will have algebraic or "Gaussian algebraic" zeroes.

Comment: @chubakueno: I would not be quite so bold with "continuous somewhere" functions, for instance $1\over [x]$...

Comment: True. A function that is continuous and not constant in an interval $[a,b]$ where $a<b$ should do the work, then.

Comment: @chubakueno: that follows from the fact that continuous images of connected sets are connected

Answer (score 8):

Let $\frac{m}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $\sin\left(\frac{m}{n}\pi\right)=\sin\left(\frac{m}{n}180^\circ\right)$ is always algebraic: put
$$
\alpha=e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}}=\cos\frac{\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{n}.
$$
Then $\alpha^n+1=0$, i.e. $\alpha$ is an algebraic number (it is a root of the polynomial $X^n+1$) and hence both
$$
\cos\frac{m\pi}{n}=\frac{\alpha^m+\alpha^{-m}}{2}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\sin\frac{m\pi}{n}=\frac{\alpha^m-\alpha^{-m}}{2i},
$$
are algebraic numbers. This shows that for a countable number of *transcendental* values of $x$, the value of  $\sin(x)$ is an algebraic number.

Conversely, it can be shown that if $x$ is an *algebraic* non-zero number, $\sin(x)$ is transcendental! This follows from the famous [Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: A corollary to this is that there must be an uncountable set of transcendental numbers $X$ such that $x\in X\implies \sin x$ is transcendental...